# Encrypt private key with DES-EDE3-CBC

Tags: security, encryption, rsa, cryptoapi

I need to encrypt private RSA key using MS CryptoAPI to satisfy this header (generated IV will be different but that is irrelevant for the question):

```
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,E7AE93C9E49184EA
```

I'm not sure if the following procedure does the right thing (memory allocation and error checking omitted for brevity):

```
HCRYPTKEY  hSecretKey = 0;
HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hHash);
CryptHashData(hHash, (LPBYTE)pwd, pwdSize, 0);
CryptDeriveKey(hProv, CALG_3DES, hHash, 0, &hSecretKey);

DWORD dwMode = CRYPT_MODE_CBC;
CryptSetKeyParam(hSecretKey, KP_MODE, (LPBYTE)&dwMode, 0);

DWORD dwBlockLen = 0;
DWORD dwDataLen = sizeof(dwBlockLen);
CryptGetKeyParam(hSecretKey, KP_BLOCKLEN, (LPBYTE)&dwBlockLen, &dwDataLen, 0);
dwBlockLen /= 8;

LPBYTE pbTemp;
CryptGenRandom(hProvider, dwBlockLen, pbTemp);
CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_IV, pbTemp, 0);
CryptEncrypt(hSecretKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pData, &plainSize, dataSize);
```

I'm unsure about EDE3 part - I can't find any reference in CryptoAPI documentation about it; will the above code satisfy the aforementioned header for the encrypted key?

Comment: It appears you need to produce output that is compatible with the [old OpenSSL private key encryption pem format](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PEM_write_NETSCAPE_CERT_SEQUENCE.html#PEM-ENCRYPTION-FORMAT).

Comment: I am unsure is what is nonstandard in the PEM, (a) presence of the header or (b) the encrypted/encoded value itself? (Non)presence of the header is easy to deal with, my question is whether the posted code will produce a compatible (DES-EDE3-CBC) DER (which will be base64 encoded into PEM)?